# docker with mode and mongo using massive amounts of disk space

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I have a docker container setup using a MEAN stack and my disk usage is increasing really quickly.  I have a 30gb droplet on digital ocean and am at 93% disk usage, up from 67% 3 days ago and I have not installed anything since then, just loaded a few thousand database records.

I probably have 20k or 30k documents in my database, but they are not very large, but my disk usage increases by about **5% every day**.  A much larger data set storing the same data was in postgres prior to this and I never had issues with storage space and I was on a 20g droplet before I was forced to increase after deploying my mongo application.

I deleted most of my old images and non-running containers.
running `docker ps -s` yields the following:

My main web container shows **8.456 kB (virtual 817.4 MB)**

My mongo container shows **0 B (virtual 314.4 MB)**

Filesize from images with `docker images`
VIRTUAL SIZE
848 MB
643 MB
743.6 MB
317 MB
636.7 MB

Filesystem use with `df`:
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1 30830588 26957740   2283712  93% /

Docker copmose command to start mongo:
`command: mongod --dbpath /data/db --smallfiles --quiet --logpath=/dev/null`

I ran:  `sudo du -h / | grep -P '^[0-9\.]+G'`
2.1G    /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff
1.3G    /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt
3.4G    /var/lib/docker/aufs
**16G** /var/lib/docker/containers/9fab4a607a0155bd61b2b73...5399e
16G     /var/lib/docker/containers
20G     /var/lib/docker
21G     /var/lib
21G     /var

Is mongo really this big of a data hog, or am I (hopefully) missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disk space is full by \`vda\` files, how to clear them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713773/disk-space-is-full-by-vda-files-how-to-clear-them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue.  I had a 20gb log file from the docker container!

I guess I will be exploring options to limit this based no the docs https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/