# How can I inspect the disk usage of docker container logs on macOS?

Tags: docker, macos, logging

Docker's default logging driver is the [JSON File logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/), which by default has no `max-size`. This means that it stores logs as files on disk, with no rotation and no limit to how much disk space they will use.

On Linux the logs are stored on the filesystem of the host machine, and can be inspected via `docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' CONTAINER_NAME_HERE`. But on macOS (and possibly also Windows) the log files are stored inside the Docker Machine VM, where they are not easily accessible.

You might expect that the `docker system df` command would include information about space used by these logs, but it does not. Does Docker provide a clean way to access it?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can find to show how much disk space is being used by docker container logs on macOS is by using `nsenter`.

For a single container:

```
docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' CONTAINER_NAME_HERE | xargs docker run --rm --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1 /bin/ls -lh
```

Or for all containers, while the current Docker VM path stays constant:

```
docker run --rm --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1 /usr/bin/du -kh -d 1 /var/lib/docker/containers
```

or just log files, while the current json_file log naming convention stays constant:

```
docker run --rm --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1 /bin/sh -c "/bin/ls -lh /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log"
```

Although this works, it seems as though Docker should provide a command to inspect log file usage without needing this workaround, but I couldn't find anything in the Docker documentation. I'm hoping someone has a better / cleaner answer.